# javascript, creating <div> and <button> then clicking on that button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I've been given a widget that sales tickets to specific boat tour,
 it needs 
`<div id="wt_piersWidget" data-api-key="1234" data-tour-id="12"> </div>` container
 and some `<button class="wt-open"></button>` ,
 after click on the button it opens form to choose data and pier ro sale from. It works fine on the sites with separate pages for each tour. simple html for those pages is:

```
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href="/wt_widget/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <div id="wt_piersWidget" class="wt__start-hide"
        data-api-key="1234"
        data-program-id="12"    
        ></div>
    <button class="wt-open"></button>
    <script src="/wt_widget/widget.js"></script>

`
```

I have some trouble implementing it on the site with special "sales" blocks for 3 different tours on a single page.
I am trying to check what exact button out of 3 possible is clicked, create `<div>` with attribute values that I need for this tour, then create `<button>` with correct class and click on it. `concole.log()` returns correct objects in console, but widget do not recieves any of those attriubute values.
 I realise, that at this point I am misunderstanding core principles of how all this code works on the pages, I just do not know where to start to fix it.

```
    <!-- css for widget -->

            <link href="wt_widget/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!---------------------->
    <div id="prices">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h2 class="section-title">Prices block</h2>
                <p class="section-subtitle">
                                </p>
                <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
<!-- One of the block with price list for one of the tours (for ex. tour#13) -->
                                <div class="panel panel__mm-ct">
                                    <div class="cell">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            <div class="price-icon"
                                                 style="background-image: url('/site/assets/files/1111/icon_boat_bus.png');"></div>
                                            <h3>tour title</h3>
                                            <p>ticket info</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body" id="">
                                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                                                            <li><i class="fa fa-ticket"
                                                           aria-hidden="true"></i>ticket type 1</li>
                                                                                            <li><i class="fa fa-ticket"
                                                           aria-hidden="true"></i>ticket type2</li>
                                                                                    </ul>
            <button id="2" class="btn btn-success" onclick="setProgrammParam(this.id)">Order ticket</button> <!--button inside one o those 3 blocks, button id is how I separate one block from another, it does work -->
                    <div id="wt_piersWidget" class="wt__start-hide" data-api-key="123"></div> <!--widget template-->
                    <script>
                     function setProgrammParam(idCheck) { //idCheck stores value from sales block< so I know which one out of 3 tour blocks is clicked. 
                        var vidgetDiv = document.getElementById("wt_piersWidget"); 
                        var attApi = document.createAttribute("data-api-key");
                        var attId = document.createAttribute("data-tour-id");//creating attributes I need 
                        switch(idCheck) {// trying to set data-tour-id to correc tour, for ex. 12   
                      case '1':  
                        attId.value="12";
                        vidgetDiv.setAttributeNode(attId);
                        console.log(vidgetDiv);
                        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //creating <button> element I need
                        btn.setAttribute("id", "widgetButton1"); //with id so I could find it later
                        btn.setAttribute("class", "wt-open"); //with class widget needs this button to have
                        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
                        console.log(btn);
                        document.getElementById('widgetButton1').click(); // and clicking on that button
                        break;
    case '2':  
                        attId.value="13";
                        vidgetDiv.setAttributeNode(attId);
                        console.log(vidgetDiv);
                        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //creating <button> element I need
                        btn.setAttribute("id", "widgetButton2"); //with id so I could find it later
                        btn.setAttribute("class", "wt-open"); //with class widget needs this button to have
                        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
                        console.log(btn);
                        document.getElementById('widgetButton2').click(); // and clicking on that button
                        break;
    default:  
                        attId.value="10";
                        vidgetDiv.setAttributeNode(attId);
                        console.log(vidgetDiv);
                        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); //creating <button> element I need
                        btn.setAttribute("id", "widgetButton0"); //with id so I could find it later
                        btn.setAttribute("class", "wt-open"); //with class widget needs this button to have
                        document.body.appendChild(btn); 
                        console.log(btn);
                        document.getElementById('widgetButton0').click(); // and clicking on that button
                        break;
            </script>
    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            <!-- jquery 1.7.1-->         
            <script type="text/javascript" src="1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!--------------->  
            <!-- link to a widget-->
            <script src="/wt_widget/widget.js"></script>
            <!--/link to a widget-->
```

I posted here only one block, but they are basicly same and go one after another.
 I take the trouble of generating those div's on-the-fly, because just copypasting symple html code with different div attributes 3 times results in all buttons working only with attributes from first div, which is how it is supposed to happen, that I understand. I am just having trouble understanding why there is any difference to a widget in the example above. From my understanding, I am generating all I need only after I pressed first button, and it generates only 1 div with attributes for a tour, then a single button pressed, widget should not see difference between this and simple html example, as I see it. Initially I tried to change value of already existing , but it still opened widget with default values.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML as it would be after everything has been generated?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="/wt_widget/style.css" rel="stylesheet">       
        <div id="wt_piersWidget" class="wt__start-hide"
             data-api-key="1234"
             data-program-id="12" 
         ></div>    
<button class="wt-open"></button>   
<script src="wt_widget/widget.js"></script>`

Comment: So that's all you have when there's  *"...special "sales" blocks for 3 different tours on a single page."*? Please provide a [mcve], because your description lacks crucial info that a [mcve] could easily provide.

Comment: Sorry, added more code. My problem now is that all my checks work, and it posts in the console correct values, attached to correct buttons. But whatever magick is going on on the side of the widget, it does not takes values from div. It maybe so, that widget itself cannot work that way, but from my understanding, it should not care.

Comment: So that function would be used to generate 3 more buttons on the same page? If so, then you'll need to change this line: `btn.setAttribute("id", "widgetButton");` because an id must be unique on any given page. If your widget requires that it have only that specific id, then you can't have multiple buttons on a page... ***unless*** each button is inserted into an iframe. But doing so would most likely fail because it's a widget that probably uses external source and probably it's own third-party API

Comment: @ПавелПешеев, in your first code block everything makes sense, a button is defined in your html and then js widget script file runs, attaching click event. But when you do it by code, who is going to attach those click handlers? I mean, the script ran **before** those buttons where created. Can you explain?

Comment: @derloopkat that is exactly an answer I was searching for.  Whole spaghetti code thing is confusing. I guess now question is how can I initialize vidget inside those function I wrote?

Comment: @ПавелПешеев, by looking into widget.js, I see there's an init function for Core. Not sure if this is what you need. Otherwise inspect a button that works and find out what the function handler is. Then either attach same handler or just call that function in your code.

Comment: @derloopkat Thnx, you helped a lot, I wonder how can I close this issue with your answer as correct.
/*SO, basically, no easy way of cheating widget as if it was just a single page, I will probably avoid calling it any other way than intended, just ask widget developers.*/

Comment: @ПавелПешеев, I'll put that text as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code block everything makes sense, a button is defined in your html and then js widget script file runs, attaching click event. But when you do it by code, something needs to attach those click handlers. I mean, the script ran before those buttons where created.